# make menuconfig hangs when trying to compile linux kernel 6.1.44

Tags: linux-kernel, compiling, make, gcc

I am trying to compile linux kernel 6.1 on Debian 12.

I have installed the build environment:

```
apt-get install build-essential bc libncurses-dev libssl-dev libelf-dev bison flex
```

Now when I run make menuconfig, I get this output ant then it hangs forever:

```
  ~/linux-6.1.44: make menuconfig
  HOSTCC  scripts/basic/fixdep
  UPD     scripts/kconfig/mconf-cfg
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/mconf.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/lxdialog/checklist.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/lxdialog/inputbox.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/lxdialog/menubox.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/lxdialog/textbox.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/lxdialog/util.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/lxdialog/yesno.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/confdata.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/expr.o
  LEX     scripts/kconfig/lexer.lex.c
  YACC    scripts/kconfig/parser.tab.[ch]
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/lexer.lex.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/menu.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/parser.tab.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/preprocess.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/symbol.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/util.o
  HOSTLD  scripts/kconfig/mconf
```

I have ncurses installed:

```
# dpkg -l | grep ncurses
libncurses-dev
libncurses6
libncursesw6
ncurses-base
ncurses-bin
```

am I still missing some component of the build system ?

## UPDATE

`ps` shows these processes:

```
6322 root       S+    0.0  0.0 pts/0    03:59         /usr/bin/make menuconfig
6416 root       S+    0.0  0.0 pts/0    03:59           /usr/bin/make -f ./scripts/Makefile.build obj=scrip
6593 root       S+    0.2  0.0 pts/0    03:59             scripts/kconfig/mconf Kconfig
```

when I kill `scripts/kconfig/mconf Kconfig`, the `make menuconfig` process terminates with folloing errors:

```
make[1]: *** [scripts/kconfig/Makefile:48: menuconfig] Error 1
make: *** [Makefile:704: menuconfig] Error 2
```

before I killed it, I attached to the `scripts/kconfig/mconf Kconfig`, process with `strace`, and I see thousands of these POLLIN Timeout messages:

```
poll([{fd=0, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
```

full strace output here: https://ctxt.io/2/AABQcjjOFw

Comment: Start by looking at the children of your `make` command (`pstree`) to see if maybe one of its children are stuck. Run `strace` on your `make` command or on its child to see where it's hang.

Comment: @aviro - thank you, please see my update

Comment: BTW Firing make menuconfig does not trigger the compilation of the kernel. Only the launch of some GUI. What happens if you launch other ncurses programs (vi, top…)

Comment: Additionally you know that killing a ncurses process is not recommended since the process will not issue the appropriate commands needed to restore your terminal to its standard discipline.

Comment: Incidentally, if you get X installed and running, what happens if you launch make xconfig instead.

Comment: @MC68020 - all other ncurses programs work fine (mc, top). And I don't have X installed, this is remote server, and I am connecting via ssh

Comment: SSH ! OK what if you retry via tmux ?

Comment: An BTW… DO make the config comfortably under your local system… THEN… transfer your .config then make via ssh. This will then authentically build the kernel. (what… as stated above make menuconfig willl never ever achieve.)

Comment: You won't get a definitive answer here. It doesn't seem like a common issue, and you'll just have to continue to debug and investigate it. We can't continue do it in the comments. But anyway, few tips: Run `strace` with the following flags: `-T -tt -yy -q -f -s 512`, it might give you more insights about the file desriptors it writes to/reads from. If it doesn't help, try to run right from the start (`strace ... make menuconfig`) with the same flags, maybe it will show you some additional info about what **led** to this situation.

Comment: But again, it's not necessarily going to be simple. In `strace` you see it's writing to fd 1 and reading from fd 0. Who are they? Are they pipes? If so, what's in the other side of the pipe? Maybe you should run `strace` on the process on the other side as well? That's why I'm saying it looks like a complicated issue. It does have an answer, but sometimes in those cases you will not get it here, but just have to learn to debug and investigate it, or at least to drill down as best as you can and update your question with a more specific issue behind the scenes of `make`.

Comment: Have you tried with: make nconfig ?

Comment: In your `strace` output, I see it tries to write a lot of ncurses text to STDOUT (file descriptor 1) using `write(1`. But from your question I understand you don't see the ncurses window. So I wonder that is file descriptor 1 of your `mconf` process. Check where it's trying to write to by (`ls -l /proc/<pid>/fd/1`) and compare to the STDOUT of your `make` command. You can try running `lsof -d1 -a -p $(pgrep 'make|mconf' |tr '\n' ',')`, add the result to your question.

Answer (score -1):

> I am trying to compile linux kernel

Possibly.

> I run make menuconfig

OK but this will in no way **build** a linux kernel.
This command will only help you to build the `.config` text file in a more user-friendly way.
If you actually want to **build** the linux kernel, simply fire `make` in the kernel source base directory.

Therfore, the easiest (an possibly more secure) way to achieve your goal is certainly to :

- 1 download the kernel source tree on some local machine (whatever system physically connected to whatever authentic tty)
- 2 Build the kernel .config file under this system using whatever GUI of your choice (`make menuconfig` or `make xconfig`)
- 3 Log on the remote system via ssh,
- 4 Copy your newly designed .config to the remote's system kernel source directory
- 5 Change to that directory then fire : `make` !

Comment: I am trying to build a kernel. The process has several steps. I am stuck at step 1 (make menuconfig). My question is why `make menucionfig` hangs. Saying: "just do it on another machine then", is like saying, well  then don't compile kernel, use the distribution kernel instead. problem solved. And, secondly, my local machine does not have development environment.

Comment: @400theCat : If you caredully re-read my answer… you do not need any dev.env. on your local machine since you'll buil on the remote. Please… realize that make menuconfig won't achieve anything else than whatever text editor would achieve.